# Why am I getting a null pointer exception when trying to use rotate(degrees) on my sprite?

Tags: android, libgdx

I've got a GameScreen class that has a touchpad within it. I have a method (setTouchpadY()) within the GameScreen class that gets the touchpad's getKnobPercentY.

```
public float setTouchpadY() {
  return touchpad.getKnobPercentY();
```

}

In my WorldRenderer class, the render() method, I'm trying to rotate a sprite with the touchpad. gs is the GameScreen class

```
public void render() {
  //render stuff
  moveCamera(leon.getPosition().x, CAMERA_HEIGHT / 2);
  spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
  spriteBatch.begin();
  drawVillage();
  drawTile();
  drawLeon();
  spriteBatch.end();

            if (leon.isAiming()) {
     leonAimArmSpriteR.rotate(gs.setTouchpadY());         //This line causing crash
  }
```

}

I've put the touchpad and buttons into the Gamescreen class because it's implementing Screen and Input Processor. Tried to put them into WorldRenderer with no luck so far.Here is my logcat/console, this is from trying to run the desktop version, if I need to post the android I will

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:113)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.me.RE4.view.WorldRenderer.render(WorldRenderer.java:142)
at com.me.RE4.screens.GameScreen.render(GameScreen.java:151)
at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:191)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:110)
```

EDIT
So I've found that I had not instantiated GameScreen, when I did that it was saying that WorldController is the null. So I instantiated WorldController in WorldRenderer, but then it's saying that TouchpadY() method within GameScreen is null, set the break point and that's giving me all sorts of variables as null.

[image]

Comment: 1.  Please format your code properly.  Can you read this easily?  2.  Please post the logcat stack trace for the exception.  3.  If your question really is "use rotation of sprite within render method without crash", the answer is "fix your bugs".

Comment: Sorry had posted it from my phone, perhaps it's readable now.

Comment: If that's the line that's causing the NPE then check the values of "leonAimArmSpriteR" and "gs", as one of those must be null.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit of a noob. I was asked if I had instantiated the 2 items you mentioned, but I'm not sure how to, because gs is a gamescreen class, I thought declaring it would do the trick, and I'm creating the sprite via spriteBatch within the drawLeon() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I was trying to do the rotation within WorldRenderer initially, within the render method so that holding the touchpad steady at a certain point would keep rotation going at that degree. I would have had to instantiate / reference a lot of items within WR for that to work, so I ended up instatiating gamescreen in WR and then referenced my sprite that I wanted to rotate in GS and then the touchpad values worked within the render method of the GS. Mucho sloppy